# OS4 - window addSubview

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have an app that works fine in OS 3.*...
However, in OS 4, this line of code doesn't seem to work.

[window addSubview:[mainViewController view]];

Is there a different way to add a view to window in OS 4?
Or is it even the wrong way to add a view even on OS 3.*?

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: The code is correct.  Why do you say it doesn't work?  Are you getting any error messages? Have you verified that `window` instance variable isn't `nil`, or that `[mainViewController view]` isn't `nil`?

Comment: Hey Dave, thanks for getting back. Both window and [mainViewController view] doesn't return nil. However, say I do NSLog(@"%@", [mainViewController view]); - that kills the app as soon as it prints the log. (<MainView: 0x733f600; frame = (0 0; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7342cd0>>). The app just quit and there isn't any error messages. Thanks, Tee

Comment: Hey Dave, I managed to find the error.
NSString* toutImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_tout%i.png", tout+1];
[toutImage autorelease];

That code comes from a scroller function that I have. Basically when I comment out [toutImage autorelease], the app no longer crash. However, why would the [toutImage autorelease]; kill the app?
Thanks, Tee

Answer (score 1):

Q: "why would the `[toutImage autorelease];` kill the app?"

A: Because you're releasing an object that you don't own.  `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` does not return an object that you own (because `stringWithFormat:` does not contain `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, or `copy`), so you *must* not release it.  If you do, you'll basically end up with a "double free" (you try to free memory that's already been free'd), and that will crash your app.